# php code becomes xml?

Tags: php, ob-start

I'm trying to evaluate the contents of mapvar.php and saving it to a variable. This is the code:

```
<?php
$filename = strval(rand(0,99999999999)).'.svg';
$fp=fopen($filename, 'wb+');

ob_start();
include 'mapvar.php';
$output = ob_get_clean();
ob_flush();

file_put_contents($filename,$output);
?>

<form action="download.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="<?php echo $filename ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="dl" />
</form>
<?php fclose($fp); ?>
```

For some reason, when I open the file, this message shows up (in both Chrome and FF):

"This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

...and then the evaluated html code.

It seems to be caused by the ob_start() stuff, why is this?

Comment: how does your mapvar.php look like?

Comment: It's an svg image with php variables. Solved anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapvar.php` probably sends a `Content-Type: image/svg+xml` header or something like that. You can override it later:

```
$output = ob_get_clean();
ob_flush();
header('Content-Type: text/html');
```

Also, there’s no need to use `fopen` or `fclose` with `file_put_contents`.

Comment: Ah that was it, I modified the header at mapvar.php, I can't change the header like yours (Cannot modify header information - headers already sent). Thanks.